# Merging two columns of a dataframe which contains dictionaries and storing it into other column in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a data frame `df` which has two columns `a` and `b` which contains dictionaries and I want to merge these two dictionaries and store the merged dictionaries in a new columns `c`. One sample data point is :

```
df :

     a                 b                         c
------------------------------------------------------------
{x:{y:{z:u}}     {w:{f:{h:l}}        {x:{y:{z:u}},{w:{f:{h:l}}
```

I have `a` and `b` and I want `c`.
I have a function that merges the two dictionaries but I am not able to assign the merge dictionaries to column c.

The function that I have for merging two dictionaries:

```
# Function for merging two dictionaries and adding values if keys are same
def merge_and_add(dict1, dict2):
    # We loop over the key and value pairs of the second dictionary...
    for k, v in dict2.items():
        # If the key is also found in the keys of the first dictionary, and...
        if k in dict1.keys():
            # If  the value is a dictionary...
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                # we pass this value to the merge_and_add function, together with the value of first dictionary with
                # the same key and we overwrite this value with the output.
                dict1[k] = merge_and_add(dict1[k], v)
            # If the value is an integer...
            elif isinstance(v, int):
                # we add the value of the key value pair of the second dictionary to the value of the first 
                # dictionary with the same key.
                dict1[k] = dict1[k] + v
        # If the key is not found, the key and value of the second should be appended to the first dictionary
        else:
            dict1[k] = v
    # return the first dictionary
    return dict1
```

I am trying the following but it isn't working:

```
df_curr_hist['latest'] = np.nan
def latest(df):
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(df):
        curr_dict = df.iloc[idx]['current']
        hist_dict = df.iloc[idx]['history']
        df.latest[idx] = merge_and_add(curr_dict, hist_dict)
    return df
```

Comment: not really related to what you're asking, but you may want to reconsider your storage method or data structure. DataFrames should not be used to store dictionaries, it loses out on almost every benefit of dataframes. If it has to be arbitrarily nested dictionaries, you could just add another level of hierarchy and just keep using dictionaries perhaps, for example.

Comment: In the code you have shared you never change `idx`, its always 0 so you never leave your while loop and thus never return any df

Comment: Even when I do idx = idx + 1 before the return. It doesn't work. Gives an error instead - `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should know that dictionaries are not passed as values in function arguments. Therefore, in your current code, modifications are made to original dictionaries when creating the new combined dictionary. You can handle that by using copies of the dictionaries to work with.

```
x = {'a':{'b':2}}
y = {'c':{'e':4}}

e = pd.DataFrame({'a':[x], 'b': [y]})

def merge_and_add(x, y):

    dict1 = x.copy()
    dict2 = y.copy()
    # We loop over the key and value pairs of the second dictionary...
    for k, v in dict2.items():
        # If the key is also found in the keys of the first dictionary, and...
        if k in dict1.keys():
            # If  the value is a dictionary...
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                # we pass this value to the merge_and_add function, together with the value of first dictionary with
                # the same key and we overwrite this value with the output.
                dict1[k] = merge_and_add(dict1[k], v)
            # If the value is an integer...
            elif isinstance(v, int):
                # we add the value of the key value pair of the second dictionary to the value of the first 
                # dictionary with the same key.
                dict1[k] = dict1[k] + v
        # If the key is not found, the key and value of the second should be appended to the first dictionary
        else:
            dict1[k] = v
    # return the first dictionary
    return dict1


e['c'] = e.apply(lambda x : merge_and_add(x.a, x.b), axis = 1)
```

The final output looks like

```
                 a                b                               c
0  {'a': {'b': 2}}  {'c': {'e': 4}}  {'a': {'b': 2}, 'c': {'e': 4}}
```

Comment: Not working. Gives the following error. `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
`

Comment: Thats not an error. Thats a warning. What does your output look like?

Comment: @Santosh Yes. Thats a warning. It doesn't show any output, only shows this warning.